# Restrict php file in .htaccess based on mode/query string

Tags: php, .htaccess, mode, restriction

I want to restrict access to a specific file (ucp.php), but ONLY in registration mode.  Ie, someone will have to authenticate in order to register, but once registered will be able to access other ucp.php functions (profile editing, for example), without being required to authenticate again.

Since ucp.php is the only file with a "register" mode, I've tried:

```
<Files "^(.*)mode=register$">
require valid-user
</Files>
```

So far, I've only been able to restrict access no matter the function, or not at all.  I'm open to any alternative suggestions for how to do this.  Thanks!

EDIT

I also tried:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)mode=register(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule require valid-user
```

That didn't work either, but as you can probably tell, I'm just kind of stitching things together trying to get it to work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You have a file that ends with "mode=register"?

Comment: It's just the mode that's called from the php file, ie: "ucp.php?mode=register".

Comment: `<Files>` only matches the file, not the query string (the stuff after the `?`)

Comment: Suspecting that might be the case (I'm no .htaccess wizard as will become apparent), I tried something else.  Added to the original post.

Comment: `Require` is a directive, so is `RewriteRule`, you can't use 2 directives together like that. The rule that you have matches against the URL `/require` and rewrites it to `/valid-user`. I don't really understand what you're trying to do here, are you trying to enforce HTTP authentication (that's what `Require valid-user` is related to) for a single mode for you ucp.php file? Because if you are, HTTP Auth only requires authentication once during a session.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I'm trying to do.  I was hoping that a static link that linked directly to "/ucp.php?mode=register" would trigger the .htaccess if the mode was specified.

Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: I take it that you're saying that what I'm describing isn't possible (at least the way I'm approaching it), because Auth either authenticates ucp.php or it doesn't; it can't do so conditionally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do isn't going to be simple. You want HTTP Authentication for a single file but *only* when there's the `mode=register` query string. The mod_auth directives simply can't handle something like that.

What you're going to need to do is create a new php file, one that includes the `ucp.php`, we'll call that `ucp_register.php`, and it just executes the `ucp.php` file in the local file system, passing it the `mode=register` query string. Then, we force authentication for `ucp_register.php`.

```
<Files "ucp_register.php">
    AuthUserFile /path/to/htpasswd
    AuthName "Password Protected"
    AuthType Basic

    Require valid-user
</Files>
```

Then, we intercept requests for `ucp.php` with the register mode, and internally rewrite that to `ucp_register.php`, which requires a valid-user, which means the browser is prompted to authenticate, but the browser still thinks its requested `ucp.php?mode=register`. After authentication, the `ucp_register.php` file is loaded, which loads `ucp.php` and does the registering. To do the rewrite, you need:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mode=register
RewriteRule ^ucp\.php$ /ucp_register.php [L]
```

Probably some details that you'll need to work out to get this to work, but this is the general idea.

For example, the `ucp_register.php` file *could* look something as simple as:

```
<?php
include('ucp.php');
?>
```

Comment: That absolutely has me on the right path.  Thank you so much.  I'll follow up.

Comment: This ended up working perfectly, exactly as you suggested it.  I appreciate your time and help very much.